# Instant App crashes with more than one query parameter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-instant-apps

I submit a Run Configuration for an **instantapp** module in **Android Studio** with a Launch URL like https://example.com/?Q1=12345 and it runs fine. The autogenerated code for `handleIntent()` extracts the intent data and the query. Then I can extract the query parameter, like this:

```
queryParm=appLinkIntent.getData().getQueryParameter("Q1")
```

I then try to test passing a second query parameter like https://example.com/?Q1=12345&Q2=67890. The instantApp Activity crashes without even posting a log entry in Logcat that fires at the top of `onCreate()`.

Has anyone been able to pass at least two query paramters to the instantapp?
If so, what am I missing?

Comment: What happens if you escape the &, like so:

        `https://example.com/?Q1=12345\&Q2=67890`

?

Comment: That works! Not only does the Activity not crash but the Q1 and Q2 parameters parse out. Thanks.

Comment: Can you file a bug to Google, then link to it back in here? It would be helpful for all, thanks! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787

Comment: I have filed a bug at: https://issuetracker.google.com/75254056

Comment: FYI I received this report:   dc...@google.com <dc...@google.com> #2 Mar 16, 2018 07:50PM
This should have been fixed in Android Studio 3.2 Canary 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Refrence to [Google Issues Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/75254056)

Just tested this on **Android Studio 3.2 Canary 14** and didn't observe any crashes with using https://example.com/?Q1=12345&Q2=67890 in the Run Configuration.

If any issue persists, please report at [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/75254056) they will re-open to examine.

Comment: FYI I got a msg from Buganizer that the issue was tested successfully in Canary 14. I verified and confirmed that you now do not need to escape the "&" in a multi-term Launch URL Run configuration like example.com/?x=123&y=456

Comment: @JAW Thanks for accepting ans,you can also up-vote it. Thanks